# What is yAxis used for in a Highcharts pie chart?

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart, yaxis

Looking at the http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-donut example, I see that `yAxis.title.text` is set to "Total percent market share".

What is the purpose for doing so?

Is `xAxis` also used for a pie chart, and if so, for what purpose?

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market share, January, 2015 to May, 2015'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: <a href="http://netmarketshare.com/">netmarketshare.com</a>'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Total percent market share'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            shadow: false,
            center: ['50%', '50%']
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '%'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Browsers',
        data: browserData,
        size: '60%',
        dataLabels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.y > 5 ? this.point.name : null;
            },
            color: '#ffffff',
            distance: -30
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Versions',
        data: versionsData,
        size: '80%',
        innerSize: '60%',
        dataLabels: {
            formatter: function () {
                // display only if larger than 1
                return this.y > 1 ? '<b>' + this.point.name + ':</b> ' + this.y + '%' : null;
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: I don't think yAxis is used for pie chart, as you can see at this demo this part of code does not doing anything. I think that this is small mistake on this Highcharts example.

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński  I too couldn't see any effect, but wanted to make sure.  Thanks